# Using multiple keys with map/unordered_map (multidimensional)

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashmap

Consier I have some buckets (`vector<float>`). I need to access this buckets based on some indexes. Example:

```
int indexX, indexY, indexZ, indexW;
```

So when a new point arrives I need to put the point in the correct buckets. Now I am doing something like this:

```
//            X                  Y                  Z                  W   => Bucket
unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, vector<float>>>>> indexedTable;

// New point arrives and I put it in the right bucket:
indexedTable[indexX][indexY][indexZ][indexW].push_back(myValue);
```

But I find this very ugly, and sadly it's also very **slow**. For example accessing it for 1700 points, it takes 0.56 secs, that's too slow.

Are there any better/faster alternatives, without using Boost ?
Note that this data structure in my needs is comparable to a Sparse Matrix (multidimensional), because very few "buckets" will be filled with something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using this 4-deep monstrosity, you could just use an `unordered_map` with a `struct` containing the 4 indices as key, and `vector<float>` as the value type. Provide an equality comparator and hash function for the struct and you're in business.

```
struct indices
{
    int indexX, indexY, indexZ, indexW;

    bool operator==(indices const& other) const
    {
        return std::tie(indexX, indexY, indexZ, indexW) ==
               std::tie(other.indexX, other.indexY, other.indexZ, other.indexW);
    }
};

struct indices_hash
{
    std::size_t operator()(indices const& i) const
    {
        std::size_t seed = 0;
        boost::hash_combine(seed, i.indexX);
        boost::hash_combine(seed, i.indexY);
        boost::hash_combine(seed, i.indexZ);
        boost::hash_combine(seed, i.indexW);

        return seed;
    }
};

std::unordered_map<indices, std::vector<float>, indices_hash> m;
```

Since you don't want to use Boost, either come up with your own `hash_combine` alternative or copy the implementation from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine).

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a00fe00a7f9d229)

Comment: I'd include a constructor for `indices` that takes all 4 parameters, and I'd provide a specialization for `std::hash<indices>` so you don't have to explicitly name the hash in the `unordered_map`.

Comment: @Praetorian: I will copy the the hash_combine from there, but what about the **hash_value()** function? `seed ^= **hash_value(v)** + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);`

Comment: @llnk Just use `std::hash<T>{}(v)` instead.

Comment: I left hash_value(), it seems it's already defined within std::

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't need to access all of the points within a dimension (ie, all buckets where y==2), then you should consider using a single structure to represent your point, rather than nesting maps.

Something along these lines:

```
struct Point_t
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int w;
    Point_t (int _x, int _y, int _z, int _w) : x (_x), y (_y), z (_z), w (_w) {}
};

// Make sure the points are sortable
struct CmpPoint_t
{
    bool operator() (const Point_t& lhs, const Point_t& rhs)
    {
        return (lhs.x < rhs.x &&
                lhs.y < rhs.y &&
                lhs.z < rhs.z &&
                lhs.w < rhs.w);
    }
 };

typedef std::vector<float> Bucket_t;
typedef std::map<Point_t, Bucket_t, CmpPoint_t> BucketMap_t;
```

Applying your example use case:

```
BucketMap_t indexedTable;
indexedTable[Point_t(indexX, indexY, indexZ, indexW)].push_back (myValue);
```

Comment: very good solution. But why do I need that compare function? If I use an unordered_map I don't need to sort them... ? I believe you only need the == operator such as @Pretorian

Comment: In a map, there must be an `operator<` for your keys, so that they can be sorted. For an unordered_map, you must provide an `operator==` implemementation as well as a hash function. With the unordered_map, the quality of the hash function has an impact on performance.